# Intersection of two cones or more

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, computational-geometry, convex-geometry, programming

I need to intersect two or more cones since I'm programming a special calculator. I have some methods except for intersection which will be written. Can I intersect the cones by taking advantage of the functions? I hope and think to obtain again cone as the result, I mean intersection of two cone is cone. Isn't it?

I have rays used to create a cone. Likewise, another cone created by rays(vectors) is needed to be intersected with the other. Then I think to obtain a cone again but I suspect about that. Because Intersection of cones constructs always a cone? I hoped that there is a function in its library but there is no. I have to implement it. Please don't depend on a specific language because it is not important at all I'm asking can I accomplish it by using the functions ? If so, how ?

```
"Generators"
"ExtremeRays"
"VerticesFloat"
"VerticesOfPolyhedron"
"SupportHyperplanes"
"HilbertBasis"
"ModuleGenerators"
"Deg1Elements"
"ModuleGeneratorsOverOriginalMonoid"
"Sublattice"
"ExcludedFaces"
"OriginalMonoidGenerators"
"MaximalSubspace"
"Equations"
"Congruences"
"//vector valued Grading"
"Dehomogenization"
"WitnessNotIntegrallyClosed"
"GeneratorOfInterior"
"// Cardinalities TriangulationSize"
"// Integer valued"
"TriangulationDetSum"
"ReesPrimaryMultiplicity"
"GradingDenom"
"UnitGroupIndex,InternalIndex"
"ExternalIndex"
"// rational valued"
"Multiplicity"
"Volume"
"// new Integral"
"VirtualMultiplicity"
"// dimensions RecessionRank"
"AffineDim"
"ModuleRank"
"Rank"
"EmbeddingDim"
"// boolean valued IsPointed"
"IsDeg1ExtremeRays"
"IsDeg1HilbertBasis"
"IsIntegrallyClosed"
"IsReesPrimary"
"IsInhomogeneous"
"IsGorenstein"
"// complex structures Triangulation"
"StanleyDec"
"InclusionExclusionData"
"ClassGroup"
"IntegerHull"
"ProjectCone"
"ConeDecomposition"
"HilbertSeries"
"HilbertQuasiPolynomial"
"WeightedEhrhartSeries"
"WeightedEhrhartQuasiPolynomial"
"// // integer type for computations // BigInt"
"// // algorithmic variants // DefaultMode"
"Approximate"
"BottomDecomposition"
"NoBottomDec"
"DualMode"
"PrimalMode"
"Projection"
"ProjectionFloat"
"NoProjection"
"Symmetrize"
"NoSymmetrization"
"NoSubdivision"
"NoNestedTri"
"// synonym for NoSubdivision KeepOrder"
"HSOP"
"NoPeriodBound"
"SCIP"
"NoLLL"
"NoRelax,
```

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. That said, this question is sure to be closed as off topic. You can't prvide a list of functions from some unspecified programming language and expect someone here to write a program for you. If you show us your attempt. how your data comes to you, how you got started and where you are stuck just maybe we can help.

Comment: No, I don't expect someone to write a program for me. I have rays used to create a cone. Likewise, another cone created by rays(vectors) is needed to be intersected with the other. Then I think to obtain a cone again but I suspect about that. Because Intersection of cones constructs always a cone? I hoped that there is a function in its library but there is no. I have to implement it. Please don't depend on a specific language because it is not important at all I'm asking can I accomplish it by using the functions ? If so, how ? @EthanBolker

Comment: Intersection of two cones isn't cone (in most cases). Explain how you use rays(vectors) to create a cone.

Comment: I suggest you search for _intersection of two cones_. Follow some of the many links there. Find something helpful. Then ask a specific question here if you need to.

Comment: h-representation ? @DjuraMarinkov